# Secure in Register to wordpress with android app

Tags: android, wordpress, api, security

I have Wordpress site and an android app that connected to this site.
I  wrote a plugin that register user with incoming json data
in the details i created register form in my app and send input data with json and AsyncTask to my plugin in wordpress and this plugin register user with api.how can i secure this work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use encryption algorithm for this, with help of it you can pass encrypted data over url and write down decrypt's logic at server end so you get required data.
E.g. you can use AES algorithm.